# How is lightswitch_percent and maximum_threshold different in Motion?

Tags: motion

The Motion documentation for lightswitch_percent is as follows:

"Ignore sudden massive light intensity changes when the percentage of the picture area that changed intensity is greater than this value. The value defines the picture area in percent above which the lightswitch condition will trigger."

The documentation for threshold_maximum is as follows:

"This parameter specifies the maximum number of pixels that will trigger motion. When the number of changed pixels is above the maximum, it will not trigger an event. The result is that Motion will only trigger events when the number of pixels changes is above the threshold and less than the threshold_maximum. A value of zero disables threshold_maximum."

The question is whether an intensity change for a pixel is just the same as a change to that pixel that would count against the threshold_maximum.  For example, assume my configuration sets the threshold_maximum at 70,000, the lightswitch_percent to 70, and my image dimensions set such that my image contains 100,000 pixels.  If a moving object changes 70,000 pixels in that image, doesn't that just barely trigger both the lightswitch_percent and the threshold_maximum?

Perhaps they really are just the same thing for purposes of triggering the feature, but they just have different outcomes.  When lightswitch_percent is triggered, the next few frames (default 5) are ignored for purposes of detecting motion.  The result of a maximum_threshold being exceeded is only that the current frame is ignored for the purposes of detecting motion.